# Error `Display math should end with $$. $$$\backslash` [Bibliography]

Tags: bibtex, debugging

While adding references in my thesis paper, I copied the following `bibtex` from google scholar:

```
@article{bhattacharya2017fuzzy,
  title={Fuzzy independent topological spaces generated by fuzzy $$$\backslash$gamma\^{}$\{$*$\}$ $$ $\gamma$∗-open sets and their applications},
  author={Bhattacharya, B},
  journal={Afrika Matematika},
  volume={28},
  number={5},
  pages={909--928},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

After that I pasted the same in a bib file which I created and then I cited the same in my original tex file. But I am getting the following error in some different line which was compiling just fine earlier. Also I am not able to find any missing  '$' sign in that line.

```
line 48: Display math should end with $$. $$$\backslash
line 48: Missing $ inserted. $$$\backslash
line 48: Display math should end with $$. $$$\backslash$gamma\^{}$\{$*$\}$ $$ $\gamma
line 48: Missing $ inserted. $$$\backslash$gamma\^{}$\{$*$\}$ $$ $\gamma
line 48: Unicode character ∗ (U+2217) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...ackslash$gamma\^{}$\{$*$\}$ $$ $\gamma$∗
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: The title should be `Fuzzy independent topological spaces generated by fuzzy $\gamma^{*}$-open sets and their applications`

Comment: remove all the `$` , it's not clear what you want but pehaps `$\hat{\gamma}*$ $\gamma$-open sets`

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have changed the title accordingly but am still getting the same error message each and every time I try to compile and in the line, it's indicating, I didn't even use display math mode. Also the same line compiled without error before I added this particular reference. Don't know what is wrong actually and I'm stuck.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Did you run also `bibtex`? You should run `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex` and `latex` again to update the bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

Google Scholar is not very good when there's math in the title of a bibliographic item. The “translation” it does is really rubbish.

You need to fix it manually:

```
  title={Fuzzy independent topological spaces generated by
    fuzzy $\gamma^{*}$-open sets and their applications},
```

Here's a picture of the article header from the [Springer site](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13370-017-0483-y).

[image]

Comment: Thank you again sir. I have changed the title in the bib file accordingly but still I am getting the same error in line 48 which reads: \textbf{Definition 2.14} \cite{hussain2016weak} Let $F_A$ be a fuzzy soft set in $(X,\tau,E).$ Then $F_A$ is called\\. Here I am not seeing any mistakes.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Sorry, but that's completely unrelated. And I'm afraid to say it shows misusing of LaTeX.

Comment: Sir what do you mean by misusing of LaTex? Even after I changed the title the error message is still the same and it is showing line 48 again and again but I don't see any error there. Moreover, the same line I compiled before without any error and so I asked.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Did you run BibTeX again after fixing the `.bib` file?